# "Avoid CSS @import" Error on GTMextrix

Tags: wordpress

I'm getting the error above. What's this mean and how can I avoid this error?

The following external stylesheets were included in www. mydomain .com/wp-content/uploads/siteorigin-widgets/sow-headline-sow-headline-b88ac2022dcc.css using @import.

fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100
The following external stylesheets were included in www. mydomain .com/wp-content/uploads/siteorigin-widgets/sow-headline-sow-headline-cf2c2d01606b.css using @import.

fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100
The following external stylesheets were included in www. mydomain .com/wp-content/uploads/siteorigin-widgets/sow-headline-sow-headline-e62e936af02f.css using @import.

fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300

Answer (score 0):

use a < link > tag for each stylesheet
like this

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem of using the @import syntax is that it has a very negative impact on page load time. This is explained very well on a number of articles - here is a good example of that: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/

To avoid this, in Wordpress, you can import using a couple of different approaches. Firstly, you will need to find where you are currently importing this stylesheet and remove that reference

Once you've done that - you can import the stylesheet into Wordpress using a couple of different approaches.

Firstly, you can directly insert the import in a link tag into your header.php file (as the user Mo'men Mohamed has specified)

Alternatively, you can insert the following code directly into your functions.php file and this will load the css correctly too

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_stylesheets' );

/**
 * Add stylesheet to the page
 */
function add_stylesheets() {
    wp_enqueue_style('google-font-roboto', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100');
}
```

This approach is explained very well here: http://www.paulund.co.uk/add-stylesheets-to-wordpress-correctly